# Is there a recommended DB to work with Quickly?

Tags: 12.04, python, application-development, quickly, couchdb

CouchDB used to be the recommended DB to work with Quickly until 12.04, when it was dropped out. Now, I want to know if there is another DB recommended to replace CouchDB that works nicely with Quickly/Python?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once it's in Quantal, the recommendation will be to use [U1DB](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2011/12/22/u1db-technical-preview-release-tell-us-what-you-think/).

However, until then, for lightweight apps using Python, I would personally recommend using [SQLite](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/).